# Using MNIST data with Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently playing around with MNIST data as part of course on using numpy and tensorflow. I was running the code they provided in course and I noticed a few warnings from tensorflow when running this snippet of code:

```py
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("../data/mnist_data/", one_hot=True)
```

I looked into the documentation and read that this is deprecated and one should use MNIST from `keras` instead. So I changed the above code to this

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

my issue now is that in the course material they use this function:

```py
training_digits, training_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(5000)
```

that function `next_batch()` isn't available with keras and the original MNIST dataset is pretty large. Is there a clever way to this with keras?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: clever way is to use method descibed in tutorial and don't bother of "deprecated" and "warnings". After you learn it without Keras you can try to do it with Keras.

Comment: Already did that, sorry if this wasn't clear from my initial post. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set batch_size and use one shot iterator() as described here [Keras Mnist documentation](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_dataset_api/)

Comment: This looks like what I am searching for. I am trying to fit it into my code. I set the batch size to 5000 but for some reason when I try return `(X_train, y_train)` I get a question mark when looking at the shape.

Comment: Trying to figure this out ATM. But how do I transform a tensor with this shape for exampe`TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(10)])` to an array?

Comment: Got it working with the reduced data size from 60000 to 5000 for the train data and 10000 to 200 for the test data. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Sequential() from Keras. This Sequential() has a method called fit(), there you can set batchSize in parameter.Seee the documentatuion:
[keras Sequential](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not quite sure i understand the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your tutorial is using a different API from the keras dataset API used in most current tutorials. In using the `keras.dataset` API you are trying to 'cross the streams'.

You (broadly) have three options:

#### Option 1

Just stick with your existing tutorial and ignore the deprecation warnings. Super straightforward but you may miss out on the benefits of the keras api (the new default) unless you intend to learn this later

#### Option 2

Switch entirely to the `keras` API and find a new tutorial. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) one is an MNIST example in just a few lines of code:

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

If it's available to you, this is the option I'd recommend. `keras` is the new default. Perhaps this isn't an option or you want to stick with your original course but I'd certainly recommend becoming familiar with `keras` soon.

#### Option 3

Find a way to successfully 'cross the streams'.

This is more tricky but certainly can be done. The `keras.dataset` for mnist is just a big array after all. You could look into the Dataset API (in particular `load_from_tensor()` and `load_from_tensor_slices()`). These options would need a little bit of wrangling though because inherently (as you discovered) the dataset returned from the new method is a different type from that returned from the old ones.

UPDATE:

The [link](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_dataset_api/) in [nag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785108/2455494) provides a comprehensive example of doing this which I was unaware of previously!